# Llamar un atributo de una clase a otra para hacer un ValidationResult

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Busco la manera de validar mi modelo con **entity framework**, y con **validationResult** lo logro, pero con una sola clase, ¿qué proponen para poder llamar otra clase y validar un atributo de esa clase?

Ejemplo:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
        {
             if (ValorFacturado < (VozCargoAdicional + DatosCargoAdicional + OtrosCargosAdicional + CargoReposicionArmetales + CargoReposicionUsuario))
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Valor facturado es menor", new[] { "El valor es mayor que factura" });
        }
```

A esta suma debo agregar un campo que está en otro modelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es que no has definido bien tu modelo. Un modelo en Asp.NET MVC puede estar compuesto de varios modelos a su vez. Los conceptos de entidad y modelo en esta arquitectura no tienen por qué coincidir. Puedes tener una entidad Cliente por ejemplo con 25 propiedades, pero luego el ClienteModel de tu Vista puede contener 5 de esos campos. En definitiva, un modelo a mi modo de ver, es una proyección de una o varias entidades. 
Puedes crear así tu model para poder solucionar tu problema

```
public class MiModeloCompuesto
{
     public MiModelo1 Modelo1 { get; set; }
     public MiModelo2 Modelo2 { get; set; }
}
```

Entonces con este ejemplo puedes implementar la validación de MiModeloCompuesto y acceder a las propiedades de Modelo1 y Modelo2. Espero haberme hecho entender. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Hola una manera de validar datos en tu entidad de negocio una opción sería que uses [Fluent Validation](https://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

[JeremySkinner/FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation)

Acá tienes un código de ejemplo

```
public class ProductoValidator : AbstractValidator<Producto>
{
    public ProductoValidator()
    {
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Continue;
        RuleFor(x => x.Nombre)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("El Nombre no puede estar vacío")
            .Must(x => x.Length > 3).WithMessage("El Nombre, debe tener mas de tres caracteres")
            .Must(x => x.Length < 81).WithMessage("El Nombre, debe tener menos de 81 caracteres");

        RuleFor(x => x.CategoriaId)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Favor de asignar un elemento")
            .NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Debe seleccionar Categoría");

        RuleFor(x => x.LineaId)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Favor de asignar un elemento")
            .NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Debe seleccionar la Linea");

        RuleFor(x => x.ModeloId)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Favor de asignar un elemento")
            .NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Debe seleccionar un Modelo");

        RuleFor(x => x.MarcaId)
            .NotEqual(0).WithMessage("Debe seleccionar una Marca")
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Favor de asignar un elemento");

    }
}
```

Otro ejemplo

```
public class ProveedorValidator : AbstractValidator<Proveedor>
{
    public ProveedorValidator()
    {
        // Indicamos que la validación continue aún y cuando una de ellas falle.
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.Continue;
        RuleFor(x => x.RazonSocial)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("La Razón Social no puede estar vacía")
            .Must(x => x.Length > 3).WithMessage("La Razón Social, debe tener mas de tres caracteres")
            .Must(x => x.Length < 81).WithMessage("La Razón Social, debe tener menos de 81 caracteres");

        RuleFor(x => x.DocumentoIdentidad)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Favor de asignar un elemento")
            .NotEqual((EnumDocumentoEdentidad)Convert.ToInt32(-1)).WithMessage("Debe seleccionar Documento de Identidad");

        When(x => x.DocumentoIdentidad == EnumDocumentoEdentidad.DNI, () =>
          {
              RuleFor(x => x.NroDocumento)
              .NotNull()
              .NotEmpty().WithMessage("El Nro. de DNI, no puede estar vacía")
              .Length(8).WithMessage("El Nro. de DNI, debe de tener una longitud de '8' caracteres")
              .Must(x => x != "11111111" && x != "22222222"
                         && x != "33333333" && x != "44444444"
                         && x != "55555555" && x != "66666666"
                         && x != "77777777" && x != "88888888"
                         && x != "99999999").WithMessage("El Nro. DNI, no tiene un formato valido");
          });

        When(x => x.DocumentoIdentidad == EnumDocumentoEdentidad.RUC, () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.NroDocumento)
            .NotNull()
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("El Nro. de RUC, no puede estar vacía")
            .Length(11).WithMessage("El Nro. de RUC, debe de tener una longitud de '11' caracteres")
            .Must(x => x != "11111111111" && x != "22222222222"
                       && x != "33333333333" && x != "44444444444"
                       && x != "55555555555" && x != "66666666666"
                       && x != "77777777777" && x != "88888888888"
                       && x != "99999999").WithMessage("El Nro. RUC, no tiene un formato valido");
        });
    }
}
```

Puedes adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Pedro... agrega un ejemplo basado en el enlace por favor. Saludos

Comment: @fredyfx Ya modifique la respuesta añadiendo un código de ejemplo

Comment: ahora sí una buena respuesta :D

Comment: hola @fredyfx con este ejemplo, podría involucrar más de una clase? por ejemplo Factura y Servicio?

Comment: @Drz De esta manera se crea una clase validator por cada entidad de negocio que desees validar.

Comment: @PedroÁvila ahí radica mi problema, que debo validar que un campo ValorFactura no sea menor que un campo CargoFijoMensual y los dos están en diferentes entidades.

Comment: @Drz como se llaman tus entidades? también puedes crear una EntidadExtendida donde una herede de la otra y hacer la validación.

Comment: @PedroÁvila Facturacion y Servicio se llaman, me podrías dar un ejemplo corto? quedaría agradecido y solucionaria la parte final de mi desarrollo, saludos.

Comment: @Drz si esas entidades tienen algún tipo de relación debes de tener una propiedad de navegación?

Comment: @PedroÁvila si tienen una relación, pero con una tabla intermedia, llamada contrato. cabe resaltar que la relación era muchos a muchos

Comment: @Drz podemnos continuar en el chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol

Comment: @Drz Puedes mostrar una imagen de la relación de tus tablas involucradas.